# Unable to install twisted inside virtualenv on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, virtualenv, twisted

I am trying to install twisted inside virtualenv, everything seems to go fine but at the end this error is displayed.

**Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-14YOyA/twisted/**

The OS is ubuntu 12.04, does someone have any idea ?

here is the displayed text:

```
(solidwork)root@rico-TravelMate-5744Z:/home/rico# pip install twisted
Collecting twisted
/home/rico/solidwork/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:339: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  SNIMissingWarning
/home/rico/solidwork/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading Twisted-17.9.0.tar.bz2 (3.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.0MB 77kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Couldn't find index page for 'incremental' (maybe misspelled?)
    No local packages or download links found for incremental>=16.10.1
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-14YOyA/twisted/setup.py", line 21, in <module>
        setuptools.setup(**_setup["getSetupArgs"]())
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 112, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/home/rico/solidwork/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 221, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs.pop('setup_requires'))
      File "/home/rico/solidwork/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 245, in fetch_build_eggs
        parse_requirements(requires), installer=self.fetch_build_egg
      File "/home/rico/solidwork/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 576, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, self, installer)
      File "/home/rico/solidwork/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 821, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer) # try and download/install
      File "/home/rico/solidwork/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 833, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/home/rico/solidwork/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 294, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/home/rico/solidwork/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 583, in easy_install
        raise DistutilsError(msg)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('incremental>=16.10.1')

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-14YOyA/twisted/
```

Comment: Is there anything else in the error message? Typically pip spits out a long error message, which might help us diagnose the issue?

Comment: Exactly, i have posted the error message, the last line indicating the failure is above in bold (i think it doesn't appear in the long error message)

Comment: It looks like you're using a local PyPI which is missing a version of the `incremental` package >=` 16.10.1`.

Comment: The error is *SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  SNIMissingWarning*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install python libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49734434/unable-to-install-python-libraries)

Comment: @phd that's a warning, not an error (and an indication that a local/private PyPI is used): pip successfully downloads `Twisted-17.9.0` then fails with `Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('incremental>=16.10.1')`