# Unable to install python packages

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, macos-sierra, easy-install

I have Python 2.7 installed on macOS Sierra. I am unable to install any Python package.

When I try `pip install django -v`:

```
Searching for virtualenv
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/
Couldn't find index page for 'virtualenv' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for virtualenv
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('virtualenv')
```

`easy_install virtualenv -v`:

```
Searching for virtualenv
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/
Couldn't find index page for 'virtualenv' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for virtualenv
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('virtualenv')
```

I can't figure out what `Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('virtualenv')` is trying to say. How to fix this?

Comment: Are you using a proxy to access the web?

Comment: @serv-inc No, I tried to curl the url and I am able to fetch it.

Comment: Have you tried `pip install virtualenv`?

Comment: @mab Yes, I am not able to install any package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install python libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49734434/unable-to-install-python-libraries)

Comment: Maybe related to recent TLS deprecation of pip. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748494/1526703) answer

Answer (score 1):

If you got a resticted network you can try installing the wheel file 
directly via [`pip install virtualenv-15.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).

Then [`pip install Django-1.11.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Django/1.11.12).

That is: download the whl files from the links provided and open a terminal in the Download's folder. then type in the commands "`pip install ...`".