# pip error: no matching distribution found for google-api-python-client

Tags: pip, google-api-python-client

I am following the steps outlined in this blog post about Firebase and Google App Engine

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html

When I attempt to run:

```
pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt
```

I get the following error:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/google-api-python-client/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:661) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google-api-python-client (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for google-api-python-client (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 9.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I am on a mac.

Any thoughts on how to rectify this?

Thanks!

Edit: 
FYI: The entire contents of requirements.txt is simply:

```
google-api-python-client
```

from here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-cron/tree/master/appengine

Comment: This is a problem related to the older ssl version which are no more supported by current pipy. Are you using a Mac with older ver of osx?

Comment: osx 10.13.2 (17C88) "High Sierra"

Comment: I'll try installing the os update.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try to install homebrew first, then install a newer version of python using homebrew and then create a virtual environment using newly installed python as ur base interpreter. This will save u a lot of hassle.

Comment: yes the accepted answer on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49734434/unable-to-install-python-libraries did the trick!

Comment: for folks wondering why all pip installs are suddenly failing, here's an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49765614/1526703

Answer (score 14):

Try installing it directly using pip:

```
pip install google-api-python-client
```

This works for me.

Comment: I get the same error. Including the SSL lines

Comment: Thanks, this works for me on Windows and miniconda environment.