# How to resolve 'pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound' error in pyinstaller exe

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-oauth, pyinstaller

I'm trying to make an application that uses Google Drive API. I am converting my python file to an executable using PyInstaller. I ran the .exe file generated from the most basic python script and I got an error that says

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'google-api-python-client' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

My code doesn't even use 'google-api-python-client', yet I installed it in my anaconda environment but I am still facing the same issue.

I am adding the code for reference:-

```
import pickle
import os
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request


def Create_Service(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, *scopes):
    print(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, scopes, sep='-')
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = client_secret_file
    API_SERVICE_NAME = api_name
    API_VERSION = api_version
    SCOPES = [scope for scope in scopes[0]]
    print(SCOPES)

    cred = None

    pickle_file = f'token_{API_SERVICE_NAME}_{API_VERSION}.pickle'
    print(pickle_file)

    if os.path.exists(pickle_file):
        with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as token:
            cred = pickle.load(token)

    if not cred or not cred.valid:
        if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
            cred.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
            cred = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

        with open(pickle_file, 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(cred, token)

    try:
        service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
        print(API_SERVICE_NAME, 'service created successfully')
        return service
    except Exception as e:
        print('Unable to connect.')
        print(e)
        return None
    
s=Create_Service('client_secret_kc.json','drive','v3',['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])
```

The pyinstaller code I used to convert it into .exe is as follows

```
pyinstaller -c -F --add-data "client_secret_kc.json;." Google.py
```

NB- Google.py is the name of the python script gien above.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: maybe this question can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49763393/pip-error-no-matching-distribution-found-for-google-api-python-client

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The 'google-api-python-client' distribution was not found and is required by the application with pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61510900/the-google-api-python-client-distribution-was-not-found-and-is-required-by-the)