# Error when installing MySQL-Python in pycharm

Tags: pycharm, mysql-python, pyhook

I'm getting the following error when attempting to connect to the MySQL-Python library in pycharm for mac:

Collecting py_mysql_connector
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/py-mysql-connector/: There was a problem confirming the SSL certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement py_mysql_connector (from versions:)
No matching distribution found for py_mysql_connector

Comment: Probably https://stackoverflow.com/q/49734434/1531971 and others if you search for that message. You need to sort out why you are using an unsupported version of TLS.